# What is the right formula for this Enum.reduce and String.replace combination?

Tags: mapreduce, elixir, tail-recursion

In the code below structList is a list of structs with each `key` being a string in a template and the `value` being the replacement.

```elixir
%ParamStruct{default: "Greater London", description: "Region",
 key: "ca_cert_subj_state", label: "State/County", order: 99, required: false,
 value: "Greater London"}
```

So in the one above the `key` is `ca_cert_subj_state` and value is `Greater London`

This is the string in which the replacements are made:

```elixir
sslCmd = """
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 \
 -key {{key-file-pass}}.key \
 -days 3650 \
 -out {{key-file-pass}}.pem \
 -subj ""\
/C={{ca_cert_subj_country}}\
/ST={{ca_cert_subj_state}}\
/L={{ca_cert_subj_location}}\
/O={{ca_cert_subj_organization}}\
/OU={{ca_cert_subj_org_unit}}\
/CN={{ca_cert_subj_common_name}}\
/emailAddress={{ca_cert_email}}\
"""
```

```elixir
Enum.reduce(structList, sslCmd, fn(x, sslCmd) -> sslCmd = String.replace(sslCmd, "{{#{x.key}}}", x.value)
  end)
```

This code is supposed to accumulate the result of changing the strings in sslCmd but clearly doesn't work. I am not sure how it should recurse or iterate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is confusion between two different values that both named `sslCmd`. Also `sslCmd` assignment in function is redundant.

Here is working code example:

```
defmodule ParamStruct do
  defstruct default: nil, description: nil, key: nil, label: nil, order: nil, required: false, value: nil
end

structList = [
  %ParamStruct{default: "Greater London", description: "Region",
    key: "ca_cert_subj_state", label: "State/County", order: 99, required: false,
    value: "Greater London"},
  %ParamStruct{key: "ca_cert_subj_country", value: "United Kingdom"}
]

sslCmd = """
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 \
 -key {{key-file-pass}}.key \
 -days 3650 \
 -out {{key-file-pass}}.pem \
 -subj ""\
/C={{ca_cert_subj_country}}\
/ST={{ca_cert_subj_state}}\
/L={{ca_cert_subj_location}}\
/O={{ca_cert_subj_organization}}\
/OU={{ca_cert_subj_org_unit}}\
/CN={{ca_cert_subj_common_name}}\
/emailAddress={{ca_cert_email}}\
"""

sslCmd = Enum.reduce(structList, sslCmd, fn(x, acc) -> 
    String.replace(acc, "{{#{x.key}}}", x.value) end)
```

Note that `sslCmd` is reassigned to the result of `Enum.reduce/3`.